# Create MS Access password protected file using java program with Jackcess api

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jackcess

I created ms access file using Jackcess api with following code, File is create successfully in all format mdb, accdb;

```
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.ColumnBuilder;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Database;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.Table;
import com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.TableBuilder;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

/**
 *
 * @author sarath_ivan
 */
public class JackcessLibrary {

    private static Database createDatabase(String databaseName) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(databaseName);
        Database db = new DatabaseBuilder(file).setFileFormat(Database.FileFormat.V2007).create();

        return db;
    }

    private static TableBuilder createTable(String tableName) {
        return new TableBuilder(tableName);
    }

    public static void addColumn(Database database, TableBuilder tableName, String columnName, Types sqlType) throws SQLException, IOException {
        tableName.addColumn(new ColumnBuilder(columnName).setSQLType(Types.INTEGER).toColumn()).toTable(database);
    }

    public static void startDatabaseProcess() throws IOException, SQLException {
        String databaseName = "C:/employeedb.accdb"; // Creating an MS Access database
        Database database = createDatabase(databaseName);

        String tableName = "Employee"; // Creating table
        Table table = createTable(tableName).addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Id").setSQLType(Types.INTEGER).toColumn()).addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Name").setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR).toColumn()).addColumn(new ColumnBuilder("Emp_Employer").setSQLType(Types.VARCHAR).toColumn()).toTable(database);

        table.addRow(122875, "Sarath Kumar Sivan", "Infosys Limited.");//Inserting values into the table
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
        JackcessLibrary.startDatabaseProcess();
    }
}
```

But I want to set password to database file, It is possible using java program ?